# Keras - Difference between output_shape and actual shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build a neural network using some layers from a pretrained ResNet50 ( the one included in keras.applications ) 
To do it, I'm using the get_layer method of the model. like this.

```
input = Input(  (224, 224 , 3) )
resnet = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', pooling=max, include_top = False , input_tensor=input  )
firstconv = resnet.get_layer("conv1")
```

then I print out the shape of firstconv with:

```
print( firstconv.output_shape )
```

And I get the expected result ( according to the model.summary() ) : (?, 112 , 112 , 64 )

Then later on the code I call the firstconv layer over the input tensor:

```
x = firstconv( inputs )
```

Then I print the shape of this `x`  and i get ( ? , 109 , 109 , 64 ) after that the code breaks because the shape conflicts.

I want to know why this is happening, and how can I fix it. I'm still learning from keras and deep learning, and maybe there is something wrong with the way I try to access the layers inside Resnet50.

Thanks in advance

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 , Keras 2.1.4 , and Tensorflow 1.6 installed from pip as backend for keras.

EDIT:

```
        self.input = Input(  (224, 224 , 3) )

        self.resnet = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', pooling=max, include_top = False , input_tensor=self.input  )

        for layer in self.resnet.layers:
            layer.trainable = False 
        self.firstconv = self.resnet.get_layer("conv1")
        print(" first convt output ") 
        # this outputs (? , 112 , 112 , 3) , the desired shape
        print( self.firstconv.output_shape )
        ... later on the code 
        x = self.firstconv( self.input) 
        print( x.shape ) 
        # this outputs ( ? , 109 , 109 , 64 ), but the expected shape is ( ? , 112 , 112 , 64 )
```

That is. in between the code I'm not doing anything on self.firstconv or input

Answer (score 0):

**Sample Code of ResNet50**

```
model = ResNet50(weights = "imagenet",
                 include_top = False,
                 input_shape = (224,224, 3))
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
x = model.output
# flatten outputs of resnet
x = Flatten()(x)
# add a fully connected layer
predictions = Dense(1, activation = "sigmoid")(x)
# build the model
model_final = Model(inputs = model.input, outputs = predictions)
```

Your description is little bit vague about how to reappear that problem and  purpose of code. Sample code here gives correct way of handling inputs and outputs with ResNet50.

Comment: Hi. It doesn't work. I set trainable to False in all layers before accessing them with get_layer , but I'm still getting the same shape problem.

Comment: What about post all the code so that we can reappear that error.

Comment: Hi, I added a more completed piece of code to the post. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found what was going weird in this case.

I was working from two different machines, and when I printed the resnet.summary() in the first one ( at home ) it told me that the first layer of the restnet model was **conv1**  so I kept this information on mind and set up to work in the other machine, later after trying many times I finally realize that in that second machine the first layer of Resnet is **conv1d_pad** and this layer is taking the (224,224,3) input and turning it into (230 ,230 ,3 ) and that is the origin of the misshape issue. I still don't know why this difference exists, but I was able to overcome the problem.